# Add new tag if another tag has certain text using jQuery or ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

I use ASP.NET Core based CMS for my website.

What I need is to add new div tag with class button_two if tag h1 item_title has this text "Peow, Wow.".

How can I do it using ASP.NET code or using jQuery (using closest and append)?

**[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9zcshea)**

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Any Title
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Any Title
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Title Peow, Wow.
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Any Title
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Title Peow, Wow.
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:contains()` selector , `next()` and `append()'

```js
$('h1:contains("Peow, Wow")')
       .next('.buttons')
       .append('<div class="button_one">BUTTON ONE</div>')
```

```css
.button_one {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Any Title
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Any Title
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="item_title">
      Title Peow, Wow.
    </h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button_one">
        <input type="button" value="buy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it doesn't work...

Comment: Well it works fine when you run the demo in my answer. What is different? ALso does the code run before the elements exist?

Comment: I use it this way <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.product-title a:contains("ул. Высоцкого,")')
   .next('.add-info');
   .append('<div class="button_one">BUTTON ONE</div>');
 });
    </script>

Comment: Also tried as you answered...

Comment: And I put it before BODY tag closes.

Comment: This code applies only once or to every item div?

Comment: Should work for all matches. Create an example in jsfiddle.com since the selectors you are using are completely different than the html provided in the question so it is not a [mre]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u96e0n53/1 need to add new div inside closest div.add-info if h2 has exactly this text match "ул. Высоцкого,"

Comment: I have many div.item-box with different titles. I need to apply code for exactly that title which has text "ул. Высоцкого,"

Comment: Can you help me, please?